# Using Selenium with Com Ports (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, serial-port, nunit

I have a Selenium Test Suite (using NUnit) that goes and talks to the web.

I have a port initializer that opens up a USB (Com) port with some external device.

However, when running the port initializer inside of the NUnit framework, it spins out, and I get no response from the test explorer. I doubt the issue is with the code, I suspect it's with how Selenium functions, but I will attach a section of it just in case.

Here's the example:

```
// Assume I have IO Ports, NUnit, and System initialized.

[TestFixture]
    class CartToucher
    {
        static bool _continue;
        static SerialPort _serialPort;
        

        [SetUp]
        public static void ComSelection()
        {

                string name;
                string message;
                StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
                Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

                // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
                _serialPort = new SerialPort();


                // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
                _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
                _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

                // Set the read/write timeouts
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
                _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

                _serialPort.Open();
                _continue = true;
                readThread.Start();

                Console.Write("Name: ");
                name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");


                while (_continue)
                {
                    message = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
                    {
                        _continue = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _serialPort.WriteLine(String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
                    }
                }

                readThread.Join();
                _serialPort.Close();
                static void Read()
                {
                    while (_continue)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine(message);
                        }
                        catch (TimeoutException) { }
                    }
                }
                static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
                
                {
                    string portName;

                    Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
                    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
                    }

                    Console.Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
                    portName = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (portName == "" || !(portName.ToLower()).StartsWith("com"))
                    {
                        portName = defaultPortName;
                    }
                    return portName;
                }
        }
```

Below this section, I run some 'tests' to select my Com Port using Console.WriteLine("COM15");. However, I never see the terminal screen.

Comment: Why not insert a debug log output in a suitable place to find out what is working and how far it is working, and if there is a deadlock somewhere?

Comment: Hey, great idea. I added Debug.WriteLine("Send to debug output."); to various portions of the script. When running in "Debug" mode, I get the one right after my initializers (Using System, Using etc, etc), but nothing after that point. When I run from the test manager, I don't get any debug output, which is to be expected.